# Running a shapiro test in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution

If I got a table like:

```
group1   group2    frequency
  A        B          1
  A        A          2
  A        D          4
  A        C          1
  B        B          1
  B        D          5
  B        C          6
  B        A          3
  .        .          .
  .        .          .
  .        .          .
```

I want to run a shapiro test group by "group1". The result I want is:

```
group1    statistics       p.value
  A       0.9475648     1.228816e-01                                 
  B       0.7533102     6.058378e-06
  .           .               .
  .           .               .
  .           .               .
```

Does anyon have a clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
tab <- data.frame(group1=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), group2=c("B","A","D","C","B","D","C","A"), frequency=c(1,2,4,1,1,5,6,3))
do.call(rbind, by(tab, tab$group1, function(x) unlist(shapiro.test(x$frequency)[c("statistic","p.value")])))
```

or this:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(tab, .(group1),  
    function(x) unlist(shapiro.test(x$frequency)[c("statistic","p.value")]))
```

Comment: Yep, something like that - here's a data.table translation `dat[, shapiro.test(frequency)[c("statistic","p.value")], by=group1]`

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(group1) %>% 
  do(data.frame(shapiro.test(.$frequency)[c("statistic", "p.value")]))

#   group1 statistic   p.value
#   (fctr)     (dbl)     (dbl)
#1      A 0.8274267 0.1611906
#2      B 0.9630724 0.7982271
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(group1=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), 
       group2=c("B","A","D","C","B","D","C","A"), 
       frequency=c(1,2,4,1,1,5,6,3))
```